# $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(a) = f(b)$. Show $\exists c \in [a, \frac{a+b}{2} ]$ with $f(c)=f(c+\frac{b-a}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-writing

Let $f$ be a real valued and continuous function over $[a,b]$ with $a <b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ , My question here is :

> **Question (claim):** How to show that : there  exists  $c \in [a, \frac{a+b}{2} ]$ such that : $f(c)=f(c+\frac{b-a}{2})$.

**Note:** I have tried intermediate values but I didn't succeed.

Comment: use rolle's theorem (there is a point $d$ where function neither increasing or decreasing). By intermediate value theorem, the function takes all values between $f(a)$ and $f(d)$ and also all values between $f(d)$ and $f(b)$. Now if $d$ is closer to $a$, select $c$ between $a$ and $d$ and you are done. If $d$ is closer to $b$, select $c+(b-a)/2$ between $d$ and $b$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a function $g: [a, \frac{a+b}{2}] \to \mathbb{R}, g(x) = f(x) - f\left(x+\frac{b-a}{2}\right)$. You want to show that this function has a zero somewhere in its domain. What is $g(a)$? What is $g\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$?